# Allocating memory using malloc in a function, segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I am trying to run the following program, in which I dynamically allocate memory to a variable using a function called reserve. When I run the application, I get segmentation fault because of allocating the memory in a separate function for an empty pointer, but If I want allocate the memory in the main, I don't get this error. So what am I doing wrong?

**Here is the code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{

unsigned char state;

/* socket fd of the client */
int fd;

/* File path requested by the client */
char file_path [255];

/* Current file offset */
unsigned long int offset;

} STATE;


void reserve(int length, void *context_data ,void *buffer)
{
    context_data = (char *) malloc(length);
    memcpy(context_data, buffer, length);
}

int main()
{
    STATE test;
    int length = sizeof(STATE);
    char buffer[1500];
    char *ptr = buffer;

    test.state = 10;
    strcpy(test.file_path, "Hello How are you");

    memcpy(ptr, &test, length);
    ptr += length;

    char *context_data;
    reserve(length, context_data, buffer);

    STATE *temp = (STATE *) context_data;
    printf("File Path %s\n", temp->file_path);
    printf("State %d\n", temp->state);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
void reserve(int length, void *context_data ,void *buffer)
{
    context_data = (char *) malloc(length);
    memcpy(context_data, buffer, length);
}
```

The `context_data` parameter is passed by value, so `context_data` inside of `reserve` and `context_data` outside of `reserve` aren't the same pointer. Consequently, when you reassign `context_data` locally inside this function, the `context_data` pointer in `main` isn't updated, causing the crash.

To fix this, either take in a pointer to the `context_data` variable to update, like this:

```
void reserve(int length, void **context_data ,void *buffer)
{
    *context_data = malloc(length);
    memcpy(*context_data, buffer, length);
}
reserve(length, &context_data, buffer);
```

Or, alternatively, have `reserve` return the updated pointer:

```
void* reserve(int length,void *buffer)
{
    void* context_data = (char *) malloc(length);
    memcpy(context_data, buffer, length);
    return context_data;
}
void* context_data = reserve(length, buffer);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `context_data` is passed by value. So the local copy in `reserve` is changed, but not the original one. As a result, the `context_data` in `main()` is not initialized. So you got the crash.

Comment: @HA-AS but you want the pointer itself to be modified, thus you must pass a pointer to the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `main()` function has no current means of learning where the allocation took place. You're passing the pointer from `main()` to `reserve()` which is fine to allow the subroutine to modify what the pointer points at... but that's not what you need; you need to have `reserve()` modify *where* the pointer points.

```
void reserve(int length, void **context_data ,void *buffer)
{
    *context_data = malloc(length);
    memcpy(*context_data, buffer, length);
}

// in main():
char *context_data;
reserve(length, &context_data, buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

In pass by reference, you pass the address of the variable. Here your variable is a pointer, hence pass the address of the pointer.

Call it like:

```
reserve(length, &context_data, buffer);
```

And change the function definition:

```
void reserve(int length, void **p_context_data ,void *buffer)
{
*p_context_data = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass a `char*` into `reserve()` but you should pass `char**` like this:

```
char *context_data;
reserve(length, &context_data, buffer);
```

then `reserve` should look like this:

```
void reserve(int length, void **context_data ,void *buffer) {
  *context_data = (char *) malloc(length); 
  memcpy(*context_data, buffer, length); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable `void* context_data` in function `reserve()` is a local variable, which means that it is different from variable `char* context_data` in function `main()`. Its value will not propagate back to the `main()` from `reserve()`. You pass a value of `context_data` to `reserve()` (the undefined value), and then use it as `STATE* temp`, but the value is still undefined.

If you would like to update a local variable of `main()` function, you have to pass a pointer to that variable. In your case, you have to pass pointer to pointer, i.e. your code should look like this:

```
void reserve(int length, void **context_data, void *buffer)
{
    *context_data = (char *) malloc(length);
    memcpy(*context_data, buffer, length);
}

int main()
{
    ...

    char* context_data;
    reserve(length, &context_data, buffer);
    ...
}
```

Or, you can also change your `reserve()` function and make it return a pointer to allocated memory.